# Not getting emails from form with PHPmailer

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

I am trying to make a registration page with an email activation form using the php mailer library. After filling out the form and submitting the page I receive I don't receive any errors. I've checked my email multiple times and I don't seem to be receiving any emails. Since there are no errors, I'm not sure what else to look for. Has anyone ever had a similar problem before? Could it be an issue from gmail?

Heres my Send_mail.php

```
<?php

function Send_Mail($to,$subject,$body)

{

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$from       = "batoosay@gmail.com";

$mail       = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP(true);            // use SMTP

$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication

$mail->Host       = "tls://smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP host

$mail->Port       =  465;                    // set the SMTP port

$mail->Username   = "batoosay@gmail.com";  // SMTP  username

$mail->Password   = "password";  // SMTP password

$mail->SetFrom($from, 'From Name');

$mail->AddReplyTo($from,'From Name');

$mail->Subject    = $subject;

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = $to;

$mail->AddAddress($address, $to);

$mail->Send(); 

}
?>
```

And here is my index.php

```
<?php

include 'db.php';

$msg='';

if(!empty($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['email']) &&  !empty($_POST['password']) &&  isset($_POST['password']) )

{

// username and password sent from form

$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['email']);

$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['password']);

// regular expression for email check

$regex = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/';



if(preg_match($regex, $email))

{ 

$password=md5($password); // encrypted password

$activation=md5($email.time()); // encrypted email+timestamp

$count=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT uid FROM users WHERE email='$email'");

// email check

if(mysqli_num_rows($count) < 1)

{

mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO users(email,password,activation) VALUES('$email','$password','$activation')");

// sending email

include 'Send_Mail.php';

$to=$email;

$subject="Email verification";

$body='Hi, <br/> <br/> We need to make sure you are human. Please verify your email and get started using your Website account. <br/> <br/> <a href="'.$base_url.'activation/'.$activation.'">'.$base_url.'activation/'.$activation.'</a>';



Send_Mail($to,$subject,$body);

$msg= "Registration successful, please activate email."; 

}

else

{

$msg= 'The email is already taken, please try new.'; 

}



}

else

{

$msg = 'The email you have entered is invalid, please try again.'; 

}



}

// HTML Part

?>
```

BTW it loads for a very long time.

Comment: make sure the google smtp server settings are correct. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-google-s-smtp-server .

Comment: Apache configuration checks.
you must configure SMTP server apache.

Comment: As you can see settings are correct. And I test it in hosting, they told me that this function is on at their servers

Answer (score 1):

Please base your code on [the gmail example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps), as it is supplied with correct settings.

The syntax you've used in the `Host` property is fine (though not as common as setting `SMTPSecure = 'tls'`), but you're using the wrong port to use `STARTTLS` (which is what it uses when you specify `tls`) - you need to use `Port = 587`. This is probably what is causing your delay. If that doesn't work, read [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).